# Type of references in EMF

Tags: eclipse-emf

How can I get "which type of references will refer for the particular class object" in EMF(Eclipse Modelling Framework)?  Sometimes the object will refer to 3 or 4 reference types. I want to get number of references referred for that particular object.
or
How to get Sub Classes for the parent Object in EMF

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct way to get a list of sub-classes for a particular `EClass`. You will have to do the work yourself. Basically go through all classes of all registered packages and test the inheritance tree:

```java
/**
 * Returns a list of all <em>known</em> sub-classes for the specified class.
 * 
 * @param cls the super-class
 * @return list of all sub-classes - possibly <code>null</code>
 */
public static Collection<EClass> getSubClasses(EClass cls) {
   if (SUB_CLASSES.containsKey(cls)) return SUB_CLASSES.get(cls);

   Collection<EClass> l = null;
   final Registry registry = EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE;
   for (final Object v : registry.values()) {
      if (!(v instanceof EPackage)) {
     continue;
      }
      final EPackage ep = (EPackage) v;

      for (final EClassifier c : ep.getEClassifiers()) {
     if (!(c instanceof EClass)) {
        continue;
     }
     final EClass cl = (EClass) c;

     if (cl.getESuperTypes().contains(cls)) {
        if (l == null) {
           l = new ArrayList<EClass>();
        }
        l.add(cl);
     }
      }
   }
   SUB_CLASSES.put(cls, l);

   return l;
}

static final Map<EClass, Collection<EClass>> SUB_CLASSES = new HashMap<EClass, Collection<EClass>>();
```